# Dependency conflict check within maven build

Tags: java, maven

So, basically if I have a situation like:

```
      $mvn dependency:tree 
      + A:a:...
      |    +- B:b:version1:...
      ...
      + B:b:version2
```

Is there a tool within maven s.a. when I type:

```
      $mvn clean install
```

it will fail with something like:

```
      Build failed: possible dependencies issue?
```

I'd like the tool to be configurable, so I could prevent it from failing with some cases (like when I'm 100% sure that the situation with some dependencies is OK)

maybe my google skills are too bad, sorry if it's obvious. thanks

Answer (score 2):

The maven enforcer plugin will cause maven to fail if there are dependency convergence issues:

http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/dependencyConvergence.html